# mvc 4 simple membership asks to be initialized, even though it is

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have a custom table named Customer with CustomerId and Email as two fields (among others).  I want to use this in an MVC4 site.
I have a single connection string with a name of DBRuWho.
In my App_Start\AuthConfig.cs file, I have a method called CheckForSuperAdmin() which will seed my table with an initial superuser.

```
 internal static void CheckForSuperAdmin()
    {
        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DBRuWho", "customer", "customerId", "email", true);
        }

        var roles = new WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider();
        var users = new WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider();
        if (!roles.RoleExists("SuperAdmin"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("SuperAdmin");
            if (users.GetUser("superadmin@superadmin.com", false) == null)
            {
                users.CreateUserAndAccount("superadmin@superadmin.com", "P@ssw0rd53cR3t!");
                roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"superadmin@superadmin.com"}, new[] {"SuperAdmin"});
            }
        }
    }
```

When I "Register a user", a Customer Row gets created as does a row in the webpages_Membership table, and they both look good.
However, I can only register a user if I set a breakpoint at the "var roles" line above and skip over the rest of the method.

Then, with this user created, I cannot login - I get a password mismatch.

If I do NOT skip over the code starting with "var roles", I get an exception that:
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class.

This is frustrating, as you can clearly see that I DO call that method.  And after it is called, I look at it in my Watch window, and it states that it is initialized.

So, I am stuck here.... I would like to use this "Simple" membership, but it does not seem to allow me to use it simply!

Any thoughts?  I read lots of articles and it sure seems like I am doing everything correctly, but obviously I am missing something here...

More Info:  Here is my connection string that maps to DBRuWho.

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DBRuWho" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=ruwho;integrated security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am pretty sure I am connecting properly, because the data gets inserted!  I just can't seem to get past the exception when I check for !roles.RoleExists and I cannot get logged in.

Update -- I deleted all data in my Customer table and all data in the webpages_Membership table, and now (if I skip over the !roles.RoleExists code while starting up), I CAN log in.
However, when I try to step through the roles code to create my super admin, I still get the exception that I noted above.

Comment: Is `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` still being called in `InitialiseSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs`?

Comment: I commented out that attribute, so the above code is the only place it is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer.  It is in the way I was instancing up the providers.  The proper way that works is:

```
public class Init
{
    const string SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE = "SuperAdmin";

    internal static void CheckForSuperAdmin()
    {
        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DBRuWho", "customer", "customerId", "email", true);
        }
        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var users = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
        if (!roles.RoleExists(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE))
        {
            roles.CreateRole(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE);
            string email = "superadmin@superadmin.com";
            string pswd = "P@ssw0rd!";
            string credentials = API.Helpers.Misc.CreateCompanyCredential(pswd);
            if (users.GetUser(email, false) == null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"Name", email},
                    {"CustomerToken", Guid.NewGuid()},
                    {"Credentials",  credentials},
                    {"isActive",   true}
                };

                users.CreateUserAndAccount(email, pswd, args);
                roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { email }, new[] { SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this on a somewhat related post here on S/O which I promptly lost the link to (oops!)

I included other attributes that I needed to send to my CUSTOMER class, just as an example for someone else's benefit.  They are not necessarily required.

At any rate, I made three changes to get this to work.

1) Make sure you are using version 2.0 of Web.Matrix and Web.Matrix.data

2) I added the following to my web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

3) I made the code change listed above.

I did these all in this order and after #3 it started working. Hooray!  I am posting this in case some other poor unsuspecting soul tries to instance up new providers....